# how do you sort puncation with jquery tablesorter?

Tags: jquery, sorting, tablesorter

I have a column that contains address "line 2" type values.  this column can contain values like #431, UNIT 203, and APT. C and of course it can contain blank (or empty string) values also.  i need an answer to two questions:

1. How would you expect a mixed values like this to be sorted (i.e. blank  or pound signs on top when ascending)?
2. How would i pull this off with a custom parser?

currently with the default parser (i'm assuming the string parser), it is ordering the values pound signs, blanks, and then a-z values when in ascending order.  i would think that it would blanks, pound signs, and then a-z values.

Comment: By the way, I really like this question because I work in the world of hotels and apartments. :)

Comment: @Stuart B: those are good points. i need to ask the customer, but i wanted to get some ammunition from a developer community before i ask. 8o) if you post your first comment as an answer, i might be able to accept it when i get to that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer #1, my expectation would be that those values would appear in this order:

```
"UNIT 203"
"#431"
"APT. C"
```

You can probably do this by trimming all but the number away if a number exists in the string, and just removing some known prefixes and trimming if there isn't a number. Whatever you do won't be perfect, and that's something you'll just have to accept/explain.

Comment: the customer wanted a "dictionary sort" where punctuation and whitespace is ignored and the remaining string is sorted as a string. I used a custom parser that isn't auto-detected and returns s.replace(/(\.|#|\s|-|&nbsp;)/g, '') for the format function. i'm marking your answer is the solution cause it's just as good as what i ended up using.